# Install an apt package using chef.json on Vagrant solo-provisioner

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I would like to install several arbitrary APT packages using Vagrants Chef solo provisioner.

chef.json seems to allow you to execute chef commands, but I'm unclear as to how to do this.  Something like:

```
chef.json = {
  apt: {
    package: {'libssl-dev': {action: 'install'}}
  }
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chef uses [recipes](https://docs.getchef.com/essentials_cookbook_recipes.html) to define [resources](http://docs.getchef.com/chef/resources.html) that are executed on [nodes](https://docs.getchef.com/chef_overview_nodes.html) via a chef-client.

- A recipe is basically a definition of what to do (a script)
- A resource is a particular element you are configuring (a [file](https://docs.getchef.com/resource_file.html), a [service](https://docs.getchef.com/resource_service.html), or [package](https://docs.getchef.com/resource_package.html) etc)
- A node is the machine running chef-client

The `json` that you are setting up for `chef-solo` defines [attributes](https://docs.getchef.com/chef_overview_attributes.html) which are like variables that your Chef can use to decide what to do.

So you have a hash of *attributes* for Chef to use, but you need a *recipe* that configures *resources* based on that hash to be executed on your *node*

In your case you need to configure the [`package` resource](https://docs.getchef.com/resource_package.html)

```
package "name" do
  some_attribute "value"
  action :action
end
```

The package resource supports lots of different package back ends, including `apt` so you don't need to worry about differences (except for package names).

To install the packages from your hash you can create a recipe like:

```
node[:apt][:package].each do |pkg,pkg_data|
    package pkg do
      action pkg_data[:action].to_sym
    end
end
```

Individual recipes are then packaged up into [cookbooks](https://docs.getchef.com/essentials_cookbooks.html) which is a logical grouping of like recipes. Generally a cookbook would be for a piece of software, say `httpd` or `mysql`.

As Tensibia mentions, read through the [Vagrant Chef-Solo docco](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html) for where to put your recipe/cookbook and run from there.

Answer (score 1):

chef.json does not execute or define commands. 
It defines attributes for the node which can be used by recipes.

I would recomand reading [THIS](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html)
and [THIS](http://docs.getchef.com/chef_solo.html)

Some of the json content is generated by vagrant like defining the runlist attribute with the chef.add_recipe keyword in the vagrantfile.

For your use case you should have a cookbook with a recipe parsing node['apt'] and using `deb_package` resource.